# CERN ROOT Graph Style Issues

Tags: c++, coding-style, graph, root-framework

Is there a way to center the titles of a graph along the length of the axis they describe? I am using C Scripting with the root command line to create a graph from a TNtuple and I have formatted everything else properly by using the TStyle and TGaxis classes to set the rest of the parameters. My problem is that the Offset and CenterTitle methods reposition perpendicularly in relation to the axis instead of horizontally.
I want my axis to look like this (where a "." represents blank space) :

---

1...2...3...4...5...6...7  (These are the graph scale markers)

...........Title...........

And it currently looks like this:

---

1...2...3...4...5...6...7

Title......................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot set globally from `TStyle`

```
TCanvas canvas;
TGraph g;
g.SetPoint(0, 1, 1);
g.SetPoint(1, 2, 2);
g.Draw("APL");
g.GetXaxis()->SetTitle("my title");
g.GetXaxis()->CenterTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TAxis::CenterTitle() method should work.